# Predicting university course marks using historic data of class mean and student's own marks

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, predictive-models, prediction

I would like to predict my course marks for this year based on the data for class mean and my own marks for the past years. **What would be a good starting point for a model for such kind of data?**

**Input to the model:** I am currently in 4th year doing Computer Science. The input to the model would be my marks for the subjects I have taken in year 1-3 and the historic data from the class mean/variance for the subject in the previous 4 years. For example in first year I took Course X and I scored 65/100. For in the previous 4 years the average class marks for Course X was 62, 63, 59, 60 and we have the corresponding variances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect data about other students, train a model on them.  Regress your own scores, see where you'd fit in the model compared to the others, and then use the model to predict your own scores.....don't take this the wrong way, but since you are currently in school, it might be a better use of your time to study harder and improve your future scores instead of using that time to create a machine learning model.

The logic which leads to this analysis is this... normally when we use models to predict things, we do it on things we have no direct control over.  Since that's the case, we are better off trying to predict what the system (outside of our control) will do.  However, when you are "inside the machine" as you are, currently working on your own personal knowledge and scores, you have direct control over your own progress and have the ability to beat the average and improve yourself as/where needed. That's direct, internal control. Essentially you have insider knowledge and command and control of your destiny.   This is much better than attempting to predict them based on others scores and some personal variance. Your performance is not limited nor dictated by a model of other people's averages.

This is not to say that having some knowledge about your predicted outcome based on a model could not be valuable to you as an individual.  You may find that you're far below average and destined to fail at your current performance level, and then be motivated to work harder.  Or you could find that since you spend time on Cross Validated, you're far above your peers and decide to coast the rest of the way since you have no reason to work harder.

Now then, perhaps your thesis will be on machine learning models and how they affect personal behavior or ... then you may get some real value from this exercise.  However, you'd probably need to have a lot more people involved (on the personal motivation side) to get enough data to make a compelling discover.